# Why are my lights flickering at specific times of the day

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have this problem where a few fluorescent lights in my house are flickering at **specific** times of the day.

Usually it starts at 06:00 AM and also starts 18:00 PM. They flick for about 10~20 minutes and stop. It only happens in some bedrooms and in the kitchen. At other times of the day, the problem does not happen, even in times where more loads are being used (for example, by noon where everyone is at home getting ready for lunch, the problem does not happen).

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Have you spoken with your electricity provider? Have you spoken with your neighbours?

Comment: @Andyaka With neighbours yes, and they have no issues. With my provider not yet. As aditional info i can say that my house is quite old, it has around 40 years and recently we have installed some photovoltaic pannels.

Comment: Did things change when you installed the panels?

Comment: Please add type of operating gear ("ballast"). Passing trains or "tubes" can cause fun effects on CRT displays over tens or meters. Fluorescent lamps are less sensitive, especially with HF ballasts. The time windows are odd, suggesting neither trains nor elevators. Any other effects during the "flickering periods"? Noise?

Comment: @Andyaka Yeah, the problem started after they were installed.

Comment: @greybeard Sorry, can't give you that information about the ballast now. But no, i don't see nor hear any other effects while the flickering happens.

Comment: The times are odd for it to be anything turning on in the house, unless it was on a timer.  If no timers in the house it would seem to be coming from the outside power lines.

Comment: Have these fixtures been converted to LED "tubes"? If so was the ballast kept or replaced?  Do these fluorescent lights "hum" when operating?   Also, is anything particular happening in the house at those hours, based on people's routines?

Comment: please include a picture of your solar panel control unit / inverter, plus a link to the manual

Answer (score 2):

Consistently at certain times of day, would suggest Zellweger tones, or simillar signalling for "off peak" power or other utility purpose. These are high frequency (1000Hz or so) "ripple current". These are known to cause flicker in some LED and fluorescent fixtures.

Another reason can be start up / shutdown of industrial plant in the area. This would possibly not occur on weekends.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of possibilities, including:

- Utility problem
- Breaker Panel problem (and when you had solar installed, they must have worked on the panel)
- Light fixture problem (unlikely because it happens on multiple fixtures)

The problem could be voltage or something else. My hunch is something related to the solar, assuming that "after they were installed" means "*very soon* after they were installed". But I would start by checking voltage:

When everything is functioning normally, use a multimeter to check voltage between the hots, between each hot and neutral, between each hot and ground and between neutral and ground.

The simplest (and safest) way to do this is at a 240V/120V receptacle. Most people have one - the electric dryer. If you don't have an electric dryer then there are other ways to do this, but it gets a little more complicated.

Record those numbers. Then test again as soon as you see the flickering. Record those numbers. If the numbers are consistently (normal and flickering):

- ~ 240V between the two hots (208V +/- a little is OK, and 230V - 250V is OK)
- ~ 120V between each hot and neutral (115V - 125V is OK) - and both hot/neutral showing the same value (within 1V)
- ~ 120V between each hot and ground (same as with neutral)
- ~ 0V between neutral and ground

then that rules out a lot of possibilities. But if anything is different, and especially if any values vary significantly between "normal" and "flicker" then we have something to work with.

Answer (score -1):

Fluorescent lights will always flicker as long as either wire has power to it. Light sockets generally only have 1 leg cut at the switch. There is no way around it that I know of.

Comment: That has not been my experience with fluorescent lights (both the old-fashioned long-tube sort and CFLs).  It also doesn't explain the odd time dependency.

Comment: Flickering lights are usually a sign of a problem or interference.  They do flicker if you want to get picky enough, but most people should not be able tell/see the flicker, it is too fast if everything is normal.

Comment: Yes, competently maintained fluorescent lights shouldn't flicker. Not least, post-2000 they're all electronic ballasts, which do not ever flicker or hum, and which have switching power supplies so they don't care about brownouts.  of course these days most have been converted to LED, and those can have compatibility issues between LED and ballast, or a lot of them are just junk.